# Turning a game to a client-server game (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, client-server

I'm redoing a game i wrote in XNA to Unity. The XNA game was the client to a server I wrote as a console application.

How does Unity work with a server exactly, and how do you set that up?

Answer (score 0):

unity haven't any server side class
but you can use post and get method with WWW class to do anything you want

if you want good reference search about scoreboard in unity
or WWW class